# Applying CSS to enclosing div, but not to enclosed div

Tags: css, html, border

I have three HTML items A, B, C as `divs`, and an englobing `div` called wrap:

```
<div id="wrap" class="wrapping">
   <div id="A" class="...">...</div>
   <div id="B" class="...">...</div>
   <div id="C" class="...">...</div>
</div>
```

A, B, and C are correctly aligned horizontally. I want to put a border around these, but, when I define it in `.wrapping`, each item A, B, C also gets their own borders, in addition to a global border wrapping all items.

I only want the global border, or, in other words, I don't want the inner A, B, C items to have their own border defined in `.wrapping`. How should I proceed?

Comment: Can you confirm that those inner DIVs *don't* have a `'wrapping'` class set on them?

Comment: that's wired inner divs should not have a border, unless they also have a class "wrapping". And btw why not apply border to #wrap instead?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Ok I solved the issue. In fact, my CSS definition was 'wrapping.column' and not 'wrapping' only, and each item A B C had the 'column' class on their divs. I moved my border in 'wrapping' only and now it works fine. If you create an answer, I'll approve it.

Comment: @JVerstry That wouldn't be proper, you figured it out by yourself `:)`. You can post and accept your own answer. Alternatively, if you think that this thread isn't useful to others (which is what SO is all about), you can also delete it altogether.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I have voted to close it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the wrap's id to target it.

```css
#wrap { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the selector `#wrap { ... }` for your styling which includes the border?